# How do I calculate the sum of all the array numbers after the first negative?

Tags: c++, arrays, sum

Can you help me with this problem?  All I could do was count all the negative numbers.
Here is my code:

```
using namespace std;
int main()

{
    const int SIZE = 10;
    int arr[SIZE]{};
    int number=0;
    srand(time(NULL));
    cout << "Your array is: " << endl;
    for (int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        int newValue = rand()%20-10;
        arr[i] = newValue;
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
        if (arr[i] < 0)
        {
            for (int j=-1; j<SIZE; j++)
            {
                number = arr[i];
                sum += fabs(number);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Sum of elements after first element < 0 is: " << sum;
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Just store an index of the first negative.  _e.g._ `int firstNegativeIndex = -1`.  If you encounter a negative you update it with the current index, only if its current value is -1.  Then, after your entire array has been read in, loop from the value of `firstNegativeIndex + 1` up to `SIZE - 1` and sum all the array values at those indices.

Comment: The trick to solving this puzzle is to think backwards: start adding stuff from the end of the array to the beginning, and simply stop when you see a negative number. Doesn't this sound trivially simple?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik but that would be the _last_ negative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to have a flag that is zero to start with that is switched on after the first negative:

```
int flag = 0;
int sum = 0;
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i){
    sum += flag * arr[i];
    flag |= arr[i] < 0;
}
```

This approach carries the advantage that you don't need an array at all: substituting the next number from standard input for `arr[i]` is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

In  your *specific* case, there are numerous simple and efficient solutions, like [that offered by Bathsheba](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70113582/10871073).

However, for a more general case of summing elements in an array after the first value satisfying a given condition, you can use the [`std::find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) and [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) functions from the STL, providing appropriate lambda functions to do the test (checking for negative) and summation (the `sum += fabs(number)` in your code implies that you want to sum the *absolute values* of the remaining elements<sup>1</sup>).

Here's a possible implementation:

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>    // std::abs, std::rand
#include <ctime>      // std::time
#include <algorithm>  // std::find_if
#include <numeric>    // std::accumulate

#include <iostream>
using std::cout, std::endl;

int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 10;
    int arr[SIZE]{};
    // Generate random array...
    std::srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(nullptr)));
    cout << "Your array is: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        int newValue = std::rand() % 20 - 10;
        arr[i] = newValue;
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    // Sum all abs values after first negative ...
    auto is_neg = [](int i) { return i < 0; };
    auto fn = std::find_if(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), is_neg);
    auto sum_abs = [](int a, int b) { return a + std::abs(b); };
    // Set the sum to ZERO if the first negative is the last element...
    int sum = (fn == std::end(arr)) ? 0 : std::accumulate(++fn, std::end(arr), 0, sum_abs);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Sum of elements after first element < 0 is: " << sum;
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> If this is *not* the case, and you just want the sum of the *actual* values, then you can omit the 4<sup>th</sup> (`sum_abs`) argument in the call to `std::accumulate` (and the definition of that lambda).